# Why is the SQL Transaction Log getting much bigger?

Tags: sql-server

I deleted a few million records from a table, which was about 15 Gb big.
After deletion, the file was about 3 Gb big.

But when I look at the Transaction Log file, it's more than 100 GB big (it was only 100 MB before I deleted the records)? Why??

The question is not how to shrink the log file. But explanation of why the transaction log is much bigger than the sum of data which is deleted.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space

Comment: Relevant: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20651.sql-server-delete-a-huge-amount-of-data-from-a-table.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete records in SQL 2005 keeping transaction logs in check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401599/how-to-delete-records-in-sql-2005-keeping-transaction-logs-in-check)

Answer (score 1):

There are many threads about this, did you try [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166331/transaction-log-files-larger-than-data-files)? [or this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)? [or this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)?

A transaction log file that is larger than the data file can indicate that transaction log backups are not being performed or are not being performed often enough.

To fix the problem make sure you’re in the right recovery model. Set up transaction log backups if you need point in time recovery. Shrink your transaction log file.